# Problem with Moq Returns() and FromResult() methods

Tags: c#, .net, moq, mstest

I'm working on a MSTest project which has a reference to a .NET 6.0 project.

I'd like to use Moq for constructing unit tests.

In my .Net project I have an interface `IDataAccees` with a method declaration which has the following signature:

```
Task<(TypeA, Resource[,])> LoadAsync(Int32 size);
```

`FileDataAccess` class implements this interface. Inside
the class definition there's the `LoadAsync` implementation as well.

```
public async Task<(TypeA, Resource[,])> LoadAsync(Int32 size)
{
   ...
}
```

private fields in my UnitTest.cs file:

```
private Resource[,] _mockedTable = null!; 
private Mock<IDataAccess> _mock = null!;
private TypeA _a = null;
```

I'd like to correct / complete the statement `_mock.Setup(...)` seen below inside my Unittest.cs file in order to establish the appropriate Moq-management of my `LoadAsync()` method, however I have doubts about this.

```
_mockedTable = new Resource[100, 100];

_mock = new Mock<IDataAccess>();

_mock.Setup(mock => mock.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<Int32>()))
                .Returns(() => Task.FromResult( ));
```

Comment: Put a Tuple into the FromResult?

Comment: You can also use `ReturnsAsync()` method and directly provide the expected return value, in this case your value tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to return the `_mockedTable` object from your mocked class, you could do this:

```cs
_mock.Setup(mock => mock.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<Int32>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((new TypeA(), _mockedTable));
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the response

```
var response = new ValueTuple<TypeA, Resource[,]>(_a, _mockedTable);

//OR simply just
var response = (_a, _mockedTable);
```

Setting up the mocked object

```
_mock.Setup(mock => mock.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<Int32>()))
     .ReturnsAsync(response);

//OR in case moq with version greater than 4.16
_mock.Setup(mock => mock.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<Int32>()).Result)
     .Returns(response);
```